# Is using an empty base class justified in this example?

Tags: c++, inheritance, base-class

I'm writing a `Window` class which propagates different types of events, listed in

```
enum Event {WINDOW_ClOSE=0x1, WINDOW_REDRAW=0x2, MOUSE_MOVE=0x4, ...};
```

to objects which have registered for notification with the window. For each type of event, I have an abstract class which any object must extend in order to allow notification. To react to, say, a `MOUSE_MOVE` event, my object would inherit from `MouseMoveListener`, which has a `process_mouse_move_event()` method which is called by `Window`. Listening to many events can be combined by extending multiple of these classes, which all inherit from the `EventListener` base class. To register an object, I would call

```
void Window::register(EventListener* object, int EventTypes)
{
    if(EventTypes&WINDOW_CLOSE)
       /* dynamic_cast object to WindowCloseListener*, add to internal list of all
          WindowCloseListeners if the cast works, else raise error */

    if(EventTypes&MOUSE_MOVE)     
       /* dynamic_cast object to MouseMoveListener*, add to internal list of all
          MouseMoveListeners if the cast works, else raise error */

    ...
}
```

This works fine, but my gripe is that `EventListener` is *completely* empty and that seems code smelly to me. I know I could avoid this by removing `EventListener` altogether and having a separate `Window::register` for each type of event, but I feel that this would blow up my interface needlessly (especially since methods other than `register` might crop up with the same problem). So I guess I am looking for answers that either say:

- "You can keep doing it the way you do, because ..." or
- "Introduce the separate `Window::register` methods anyway, because ..." or of course
- "You are doing it all wrong, you should ...".

**EDIT:**

From the link in Igors comment: What I do above only works if there is at least one virtual member in  `EventListener` for example a virtual destructor, so the class is not technically completely empty.

**EDIT 2:**

I prematurely accepted n.m.'s solution as one of the type "I'm doing it all wrong". However, it is of the second type. Even if I can call `EventListener->register(Window&)` polymorphically, `Window` needs to implement a highly redundant interface (in terms of declared methods) that allows `EventListeners` to register for selective notification. This is equivalent to my alternative solution described above, only with the additional introduction of the `EventListener` class for no good reason. In conclusion, the canonical answer seems to be:

*Don't do `dynamic_cast` + empty base class just to avoid declaring many similar functions, it will hurt you when maintaining the code later. Write the many functions.*

**EDIT 3:**

I found a solution (using templates) which is satisfactory for me. It does not use an empty base class any more and it does not exhibit the maintenance problem pointed out by n.m.

Comment: Looks like you are doing something similar to [Acyclic Visitor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf). There, too, the author introduces an empty base class just to have something to `dynamic_cast` from.

Comment: Ok, I don't really know what an Acyclic Visitor does, but I will take this a nod towards "keep doing it the way you do", thanks!

Comment: Well, that's why I made "Acyclic Visitor" a clickable link to the article in question. Surely you must know how to follow links.

Comment: Sorry for my previous (deleted) comment - I still do not exactly know what exactly Acyclic Visitor does, but the link is indeed helpful.

Comment: Your `EventTypes` and `dynamic_cast` seem redundant: can you not simply `static_cast`, because `EventTypes` tells you the type? Note that `dynamic_cast<>` has no guarantee for an upper bound on its run time ...

Comment: If I trust my callers, I can use static_cast, I guess (although `Window::register` is not a time-critical routine for me). Still, I probably should just do that and live with "some kind of code smell"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: a visitor, acyclic or not, is always a possibility, but in this case one needs a plain old virtual call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
template <int EventType> void register_(EventListener<EventType> Listener)
{
    // do stuff with Listener, using more templates
};
```

It turned out that static polymorphism was better suited for my needs - I just wanted to avoid writing

```
register_mouse_motion_event(...)
register_keyboard_event(...)
```

and so on. This approach also nicely eliminates the need for an empty base class.

Answer (score 2):

```
object->registerWindow (this, EventTypes);
```

Of course you need to implement `registerWindow` for all `EventListener` heirs. Let them check for event types which are relevant to *them*.

**UPDATE**

If this means you need to redesign your code, then you need to redesign your code. Why is it so? Because `dynamic_cast` is **not** a proper way to do switch-on-types. It is not a proper way because every time you add a class in your hierarchy, you need to go over and possibly update **all** switches-by-dynamic-cast in your old code. This becomes very messy and unmaintainable very quickly, and this is exactly the reason why virtual functions were invented.

If you do your switch-on-types with virtual functions, every time you change your hierarchy you have to do... nothing. The virtual call mechanism will take care of your changes.

Comment: Ok, so I am doing it all wrong. This is fine, but what you suggest is a complete redesign of the way my code works (without much detail though), the argument being that "this is what they teach in OOP 101". I will translate your answer to "RTFM", thanks.

Comment: @Roberto: If you have a `dynamic_cast`, and do not have a solid explanation of the form "a virtual call won't work here because..." then yes, you are doing it wrong, you didn't do RTFM and your design needs to be rebuilt from scratch. Sorry.

Comment: I got from Igors link that i need a virtual destructor in the base class. Your answer was zero helpful.

Comment: Of course you need a virtual destructor in the base class, that's pretty much a given. If you don't have one you're up to a host of nasty problems. This is however orthogonal to the issue at hand, your design still needs to be redone.

Comment: Ok, then please (not sarcastic) could you be a little more specific on the general problem with my code. I mean it's not broken in a sense that it won't compile / do what it is supposed to.

Comment: Your *design* is broken, not your code. Code that compiles and does what it needs to do is *not* a big deal. Design that's alive and maintainable ten years from now *is*. If you are satisfied with your design then by all means continue to use it, otherwise see the update.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Given what you wrote, I can live with my design. I will not have to update my `register` function for each new subclass of `MouseMoveListener`, but only for each new direct subclass of `EventListener`, which should happen rarely enough.

Comment: Live with your design if you can, but be aware that it will not win you any accolades.